# How to combine two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to combine 2 arrays to get an array composed of the common values in the arrays. For example:

```py
x = np.array ([1,2,3,4,6,11])

y = np.array ([3,6,5,2,9,8])
```

The result should be `z = [2, 3, 6]` which are the values that are common to both.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html. `z = np.intersect1d(x,y)`

Comment: Didn't expect to be so easy. Thank you so much!

Comment: :) np. Numpy comes with a vast set of functionalities. I usually just google `numpy <something>` to see if there is a something for it.

Comment: Yes i know, but my English sometimes not good enough for google to understand :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the function `np.intersect1d(x,y)`.

Edit: also, keep this readily accessible: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/numpy-ref-1.17.0.pdf I can't tell you how much I just pop over to it regularly for those kinds of weird one-off functions.